# What does it mean to show that a bijection betwen two hom-sets is natural?

Tags: category-theory

From *Categories for the Working Mathematician*:

> For small categories $A$, $B$, and $C$ establish a bijection
>
> $$
> \mathbf{Cat}(A \times B, C) \cong \mathbf{Cat}(A, C^B)
> $$
>
> and show it natural in $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Here I'm assuming that $\mathbf{Cat}(A \times B, C)$ and $\mathbf{Cat}(A, C^B)$ denote the hom-sets $\text{hom}_\mathbf{Cat}(A \times B, C)$ and $\text{hom}_\mathbf{Cat}(A, C^B)$, respectively. So we are trying to establish a bijective function $f$ between these two sets.

**Question:** What does it mean to show that this bijection is "natural" in $A$, $B$, and $C$? I understand what a natural transformation is, but don't see the connection here to this question.

Answer (score 2):

It should mean (I don't have access to the book at the moment) that, say, if you have a morphism $A\longrightarrow A'$, the diagram

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Cat}{\bf Cat}
\begin{matrix}
\Cat(A'\times B,C)&\!\longrightarrow&\Cat(A',C^B)\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow\\%
\Cat(A\times B,C)&\!\longrightarrow&\Cat(A,C^B)
\end{matrix}
$$
is commutative.

Comment: What Bernard suggests shows that the two functors are natural in A.  You also must show they are natural in B and in C, using similar diagrams involving B' and B, and involving C' and C.